# Delphi XE3: What are the new types, MarshaledString and MarshaledAString used for?

Tags: string, delphi, types, delphi-xe3

In `Winapi.Windows.pas` of Delphi XE3, many C types that were formerly defined as `PWideChar` and `PAnsiChar` now are defined as `MarshaledString` and `MarshaledAString` respectively (e.g. `PWChar`, `LPSTR`):

```
  PWChar = MarshaledString;
  LPSTR  = MarshaledAString;
```

Indeed, in `System.pas`, `MarshaledString` and `MarshaledAString` are equivalent to `PWideChar` and `PAnsiChar` respectively,

```
  MarshaledString  = PWideChar;
  MarshaledAString = PAnsiChar;
```

but what is the background behind this decision? I mean, why Embarcadero *should redefine* such C string types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embarcadero is working on a next-generation compiler for mobile development.   The changes you see are related to that effort.  The technical details are not public yet, so nobody with info about it is allowed to say anything further about it.

Comment: Ooooh! A foreshadowing of things to come!

Comment: Is that for RAD Studio Mobile? Looking forward to that one.

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation:

> System.MarshaledString is an alias for PChar.
> System.MarshaledAString is an alias for PAnsiChar.
>
> MarshaledString is meant to be used on mobile
> platform to keep with the notion of eliminating pointers and looking
> forward, the new Delphi Next-Generation Mobile Compiler requires a
> more explicit style of marshalling data to/from external APIs and
> libraries.